# Fuzzy matching of author names

Tags: machine-learning, text

We are trying to figure out what is the best approach for us to train a ML model to identify Authors. We have structured metadata of authors (given name, surname. etc) and the task is to train a model which recognizes the author when we receive a new name. The challenge is to identify names written in different ways e.g. John Smith, J Smith, J.Smith, Jon Smith etc.
We have nearly 130000 records as input data set.

Comment: This might provide some insights: https://towardsdatascience.com/python-tutorial-fuzzy-name-matching-algorithms-7a6f43322cc5